# VueJS 2 vue-router 2 (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, vue.js

**I am trying to link between (VueJS 2) components using (vue-router 2) router-link. When a link is clicked, the URL is not updated used in blade (laravel 5.3) i used router-link and already v-link is replaced so can i get any example to use vue-router in blade (laravel 5.3 last version)**

**console error : router is undefined**

**app.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap-sass');
    window.Vue = require('vue');
    window.VueRouter = require('vue-router');
    require('vue-resource');
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    var App = Vue.extend({});
    var router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            { path: '/AddServices', component: require('./components/Test.vue') }
        ]
    });
    new Vue({
            el: '#appp',
            router: router,
            render: h => h('router-view')
    });

    Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
        request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

        next();
    });
```

**balde have link  app.blade.php**

```
<router-link to="/AddServices">/AddServices</router-link>
<router-link to="/AddServices"><a>/AddServices</a></router-link>
```

**blade have id to make action home.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="appp">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are supposed to share the code where you declare your app, routes, etc. No one can't tell you where you've mistaken if we can't see the piece of code responsible for your errors.

Comment: thanks for reply there my code

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you don't need to create new router instance

```
var router = new VueRouter({
...
```

and have the

```
Vue.use(VueRouter) // you can remove that one
```

Second, how do you expect the url to change if you have only 1 url ?

Try this router

```
var router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: require('./components/Example.vue') },
        { path: '/AddServices', component: require('./components/Test.vue') }
    ]
});
```

And here are links (and don't put `<a>` tags inside `<router-link>`

```
<router-link to="/">/index</router-link>
<router-link to="/AddServices">/AddServices</router-link>
```

Comment: i use router-link in my blade didnt make any action after click and its show in browser not link and see in console error : router is undefined

Comment: The only thing I can come up with is if you haven't installed vue-router ? `npm install vue-router` ? Other than this I don't see anything wrong with the code. Anyway here is a working example of what you're trying to achieve https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tsvetant/laravue/master/resources/assets/js/app.js from my learning sessions with vue. Maybe you can track a mistake you've made using this.

Comment: all my problem when i use router-link in blade didnt make link its show only normal string not link in browser and see consol said route is undefined and i allready instaled "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.1"

Answer (score 0):

There are several typos in your code , please check  Vue.use(VueRouter) without ';'.  el:"#appp"?, while clearup these compiler failed first. step next to figure

Comment: Can you clean this up a bit? I have no idea what you are trying to say besides that they are missing a semicolon on line 7.

Comment: changed but i have problem in blade router-link  tag is not link in my browser when i focus isnt show it link i have to add something (install) to make it work or not router-link tag is not work when i add it in blade.php see in console this problem "router is undefined" and when i put component example after put this tag this component disappear and show this wrong in console